# How to scroll at the bottom with animated in UITableView swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

How to animate the footer view a table view when the UItableView reloads?

I am trying to append an element to the tableView and when the table view reloads the footer view should come with some animation. And also if the table view contents exceeds the screen size the footer view  should stick with bottom of the screen. Here is my try:

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.familyAModelArray.append(self.childAModelArray)
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

*Note:* Here i want to append an object to an array which is the content of the UITableView and reload the TableView. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are adding stuff to your table view. What type of animation do you want? Do you want to animate the insertion of new rows?

Comment: @FangmingNing Thank you for the fast reply. yes i want to animate the insertion of the new row to bottom and the footer view go underneath the last cell with animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using animation on UIView when the UITableView reloads after appending the rows.

```
UIView.transition(with: tableView, duration: 0.2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {self.tableView.reloadData()}, completion:{ (success) in
            if success {
                if self.familyAModelArray.count >= 3{
                    self.scrollToBottom()
                }
            }
        })
```

And if length of my array is greater than 3 the footer view stick at the bottom by scrolling the UITableView to the top .

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.familyAModelArray.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This solution has given a nice look for my table view.

Answer (score 1):

To animate the insert action, you need to call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` method with row animation.

After adding table cell elements to your array, you must calculate the index paths for the new cells to be displayed, and create an array of them, like this

```
let indexes = [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)]
```

Then simply call the following method to animate the insertion

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexes, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the footer view to stick on the bottom of your screen, then it shouldn't be a footer view. it should be a custom UIView that is pinned to your view controller's view. Whenever you call a reloadData() on your tableView, you can likewise call a present/animate function on your new custom view that you pinned to the bottom & animate it on / off the screen.